# Sul significato dell'espressione "Le pigne, le pigne"

Tags: grammar, meaning, regional

Ho letto questo dialogo:

> Persona A: La Svizzera attira le imprese italiane con piani di pressione fiscale a bassi livelli e costanti nel tempo e noi ...
>
> Persona B: Le pigne, le pigne.

Che significa "Le pigne, le pigne"?

È per caso un'espressione regionale? Se sì, di dove?

Comment: Non so se c'entra, ma "avere le pigne in testa" significa essere stupidi, fare sciocchezze, ecc.

Comment: Walter, chissà, può darsi sì. E dove si dice?

Comment: sicuramente molto usata come espressione a Roma

Comment: Se posso fidarmi di una ricerca su Internet, soltanto nel Devoto-Oli si trova un _roman._ che la denota come espressione romanesca. Ipotizzo che l'espressione sia nata a Roma e si sia diffusa in tutta l'Italia.

Comment: @WalterTross Tutta Italia no. In Friuli/Veneto non l'avevo mai sentita usare. Al massimo ho sentito usare l'espressione *pigna in culo*, che però ha un significato completamente diverso...

Comment: @Bakuri, io in Sicilia ho sentito *pigghianculu* che forse è equivalente.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: no, perché _pigghiari_ significa _pigliare_, cioè _prendere_

Answer (score 3):

L'espressione *le pigne* in questo contesto sembra essere analoga alla più volgare *le balle* (o *ste balle*) usata per esprimere scetticismo, spesso in modo sarcastico.

Può darsi che si tratti di un'espressione regionale, ma in Lombardia e dintorni non l'ho mai sentita usare, nemmeno in altri contesti.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @A.P.!

Comment: Grazie, @Charo.

Answer (score 1):

"Avere le pigne in testa" è un'espressione molto usata a Roma e dintorni, ma è anche riportata da molti dizionari della lingua italiana (a volte con la specificazione di voce regionale o romanesca).